# create-react-app — how to set EXTEND_ESLINT to true?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, eslint

I have created a `.env` file in my project root but I'm new to working with environments / variables and so I'm unsure how to integrate the file so I can override the stock, non-ejected react-app eslint settings.

```
// My .env file has just this

EXTEND_ESLINT = "true"
```

The [c-r-a docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config) explain what the variable is, but not now to set it to true. Also, the section on 'Extending the ESLint config' is helpful only for once the var is set to true.

```
// stock create-react-app package.json

"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? did you try what you want to do and are getting an error?

Comment: @azium I'm trying to override the eslint settings in a create-react-app (not ejected). The docs say you must set EXTEND_ESLINT to true, but I'm not sure how to do that. After that I [think] I can just create my own .eslintrc.js file and add rules.

Comment: the docs say to update the `.env` which you have.. did you try to override anything yet? does it not work?

Comment: I seem to have stumbled on the answer. I created an .eslintrc file (no extension) and added my overrides and it worked. I think with the EXTEND_ESLINT var set in the .env file it works now. lol. No idea how I did that, just kept trying things.

Comment: You never said it was broken in the first place. anyways, the docs are pretty clear, I would just follow what they say and you should be good for this and other CRA related issues

Answer (score 25):

In the project root directory, you can create the `.env` file with `EXTEND_ESLINT` set to `true` so as to extend the ESLint config:

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

Also this also works:

```
EXTEND_ESLINT = "true"
```

Tried with [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) version 3.4.1, the latest version at the time of writing.

As an example, you can override the `no-unused-vars` rule in the `package.json`, as below:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
...
```

Now run the linter, e.g., `npm run lint`, you will not see any warning even if you have assigned a value to a variable but never used it in your application, kind of warning which you would normally see by the default settings. For example:

```
const App = () => {
  let myVar = 1; // Never used
  ...
}
```

**Note**: `npm start` and `npm run build`, etc., will also honour the extended rules.

---

By the way, the original `package.json` looks like this:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
...
```

**Note**: Another way to configure ESLint is to remove the `eslintConfig` entry from the `package.json` file and create `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json` in the project root directory as below:

```
{
 "extends": ["react-app"],
 "rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }
}
```

---

**[Update]** If you find that react-scripts is not honouring your change to the ESLint rules, it is most likely caused by the cache. It is [an open issue of the project](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9007) at the moment. You can manually disable the cache in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` like below:

```
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                cache: true, // You can set it to false
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                ignore: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                baseConfig: isExtendingEslintConfig
                  ? undefined
                  : {
                      extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
                    },
                useEslintrc: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                // @remove-on-eject-end
              },
```

Note that this workaround would only be for your local development. You don't need to do anything for your build pipeline most likely, as the pipeline usually builds from scratch; so there is no such cache issue out there.

Comment: This does not work. When I run the `npm run eslint` command it works. But when I run `npm run dev` the errors still show up.

Comment: @EnZo thanks for the comments. See the note in my updated answer, and it should work for `npm run dev` in your setup with environment variable EXTEND_ESLINT set to true.

Comment: Still not working, I have the exact same configuration in the `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` line in my `.env`. And also the `{
 "extends": ["react-app"],
 "rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }
}` in the `package.json`. Tried also as `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json`

Comment: Which create-react-app version do you use? @EnZo or more info about your react version, react-scripts version, etc.?

Comment: @EnZo, it's about eslint cache, see my reply: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9007

Comment: I just had to upgrade `"react-scripts": "3.4.1"`. Thank you @Yuci.

Comment: Please take my upvote. I was skeptical, but setting `cache: false` fixed it for me. Thank you

Comment: @Yuci your advice about `cache` flag in the `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` solved my weird problems with custom config :D Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you! It was the cache thing for me also. I was stuck on this for days!

Answer (score 6):

After struggling for hours, thanks to @Yuci my eslint is finally understanding my configurations.

Instead of directly fixing the package file in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`, I have added npm scripts to always bust out the cache in start of `npm run start` and `npm run build`.
This way you don't have to fear for 'accidentally' rebuilding the package in the future by `rm -rf node_modules; npm install` -- future me is not that clever.

in `packages.json`, change the scripts entity like the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run clear_cache:eslint && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run clear_cache:eslint && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "clear_cache:eslint": "rm -rf node_modules/.cache/eslint-loader"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

a short answer is to just inline in the `script` command like

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "EXTEND_ESLINT=true react-scripts start"
  }
}
```

but this is less than ideal since you'd have to add `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` to all the other `react-script` commands as well