# Trying to disable no-template-curly-in-string ESlint rule on my project

Tags: eslint

Getting this error

```
./src/locale/translations.js
  Line 4:5:   Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string
  Line 6:13:  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string
```

And trying to disable for the whole project:

```
// .eslintrc
{
    "rules": {
        "no-template-curly-in-string": "off",
        "template-curly-in-string": "off"
        // "no-template-curly-in-string": 0,
        // "template-curly-in-string": 0
        // "no-template-curly-in-string": false,
        // "template-curly-in-string": false
    }
}
```

None of those work.

Comment: `"no-template-curly-in-string": "off",` should work, are you sure that configuration file is getting loaded? What if you name it `.eslintrc.json` per [the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app and to be honest, I'm not sure if the eslintrc file is being loaded or not. Tried with `.eslintrc.json` but still not working.

Comment: Then did you read https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config?

Comment: More context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290876/create-react-app-how-to-set-extend-eslint-to-true#comment109185208_61463282

I think is more a problem of CRA than ESLint. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to react-scripts@4.0.0 because I found an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8683) in the previous version 3.X.X where the eslint was ignored.

Update:

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@4.0.0
```

or

```
yarn add --exact react-scripts@4.0.0
```

This works in my case ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable it with the following:

// package.json

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-template-curly-in-string": "off"
    }
```

The trick was to add `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` to my environment file after updating package.json, and then restarting my server.