# Overwriting the CRA basic linting rules

Tags: create-react-app, linter

I have an application created using the create-react-app.
I need to disable one rule from the default CRA Lint rules:

```
"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0
```

After checking all of the resources about the topic and I'm still failing to disable that rule. I made an .env file with `EXTEND_ESLINT=true`
and I've included the following in my .eslintrc in the root directory

```
{
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": ["react-app"],
        "overrides": [
            {
                "rules": {
                    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT based on the comments suggestions:

Aditionally, moving the `.eslintrc` conents to `package.json` is not working either.

Package.json

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "shared-config"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0
    }
  },
```

Am i missing something ? Please advice if possible :)

Comment: `overrides` needs `files` (see e.g. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-only-for-a-group-of-files), you just want a top-level `rules` by the look of it.

Comment: So I should include all of the .js files in that array right ? Something like *.js

Comment: If you want it to apply to everything, just don't put it in overrides.

Comment: If I remove the overrides and put the rules: {...} below the "extends" and I re-start the app - it still fails

Comment: Oh, you're also mixing the config-in-`package.json` format, where the ESLint config is under a top-level `"eslintConfig"` key, and config-in-`.eslintrc` where the config should be the root object.

Comment: Ok so I guess it should be more like {
        "extends": ["react-app"],
                "rules": {
                    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0
                }
}

I can still see the warnings after the app re-start ;/

Comment: Maybe it's caching per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61463282/3001761 or maybe they *only* support the package.json version (that's what's shown in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config).

Comment: I tried both options with no luck. I made an edit to the post with the current package.json form